# Angular project is compiling successfully but has many errors in html file

Tags: html, angular, npm, abp

I use Angular, and ABP, and I installed npm packages. The project was compiled successfully and the page was opened but there are so many errors occurred. Especially there are many irrelevant errors from each other in the HTML file. I don't know the reason why this is occurring. Could someone tell me, please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look like linting errors, what are the actual errors? They will tell you where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by *updating* the **Angular Language Services** Extension *(v14.0.1)*. You can press **Ctrl+Shift+X** and then find the Angular Language Services.